# Error when trying to read in data to AWS SageMaker from S3 within VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am in a VPC trying to read in data (using Python) from an S3 bucket into a Jupyter notebook hosted on a SageMaker notebook instance and I get the following error:

ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443 ssl:default [Temporary failure in name resolution]

Any thoughts on remedies?

Comment: Is DNS resolution enabled in the VPC? You can check it by selecting the VPC and than `Actions` -> `Edit DNS resolution` -> enable `DNS resolution`

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi - Yes it is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Which subnet do you use? private/public/isolated?
make sure you have a NAT gateway or internet gateway.

(p.s. maybe attach some code for other suggestions)